# Java : distinguish between read and close IOException?

Tags: java, ioexception

Here is the simplified code :

```
public static void cat(File file) {
    try (RandomAccessFile input = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")){
        String line = null;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        return;
    } catch(FileNotFoundException a){
        ;//do something to recover from this exception.
    }catch(IOException b){
        ;//distinguish between close and readLine exception.
    }
}
```

There are two situations when we may get `IOEception` :

1. Everything works out fine except closing the `input`.
2. `readLine` throws and `IOException.`

So how to distinguish between these two situations? Is there a good method to do this? Or should I just be reduced to do some string comparison of the exception message to distinguish between these two `IOException`?

Thanks! I just can't find a easy method to do this.

Comment: In practice this `close()` will never throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a flag just before return

```
public static void cat(File file) {
    boolean readAll = false;
    try (RandomAccessFile input = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")){
        String line = null;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        readAll = true;
        return;
    } catch(FileNotFoundException a){
        ;//do something to recover from this exception.
    }catch(IOException b){
        ;//distinguish between close and readLine exception.
        if (readAll) ...
    }
}
```